# CameraX cameraView and previewView

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-camerax

What is different between camerax cameraView and previewView? because i can't find resources or articles about comparing 2 view for previewing camerax

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`PreviewView` is a custom View you can use to display a camera preview. You can add it to your XML layout, then in your `Activity`/`Fragment`, hook it up with a `Preview` use case to get the preview stream started. So while using `PreviewView`, you're responsible for setting up the camera, creating the `Preview` use case (and other use cases you may want to use), and binding them to a lifecycle. You can read more about `PreviewView` and how it works in [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/display-a-camera-preview-with-previewview-86562433d86c).

`CameraView` is a custom View that does many things, it was built to allow users to quickly set up a "camera app" by adding the View in their XML layout. It allows to display a camera preview, take pictures, record videos, zoom in/out on the viewfinder, and provides different APIs to configure the camera (lens facing, flash, scale type, capture mode, etc). It handles setting up the camera, binding and unbinding the use cases and what not. An important thing to note is that for displaying a preview, it internally uses `PreviewView`. I haven't come across many articles online on `CameraView`, I'd recommend [this one](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-camerax-on-android-camera-view-daae6dfaa4ec) though.

If you need flexibility in setting up the camera and building/configuring the use cases, or if you need to use the `ImageAnalysis` use case, then `CameraView` is probably not the right choice to go with. `PreviewView` was built to offload the burden of setting up and handling the preview surface used by the camera, and handling the hard bits of displaying a preview (scaling, rotating, aspect ratio, etc).

Comment: I am building app with video kyc feature.Which records user selfie video. Which approach should i use PreviewView or CameraView?

Comment: @Joker `PreviewView` only handles the camera preview, your use case requires video recording, which `PreviewView` doesn't handle. `CameraView` supports recording videos with its [startRecording()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/CameraView#startRecording(java.io.File,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback)) and [stopRecording()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/CameraView#stopRecording()) methods. Keep in mind though that they're both experimental features, and might not be 100% stable.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.so currently stable approach will be using Camera2 API.